# Minimize total struct memory

Tags: c++, struct, memory-alignment

I have a `struct`:

```
struct st
{
    short a;
    int *b;
    char ch;
};
```

`short` is 2 bytes
`int*` is 8 bytes in x64
`char` is 1 bytes

All the above together should give me 11 bytes. But if I do `sizeof(st)` I get 24 bytes. Why the `struct` uses more memory and how to reduce the memory to 11 bytes?

Comment: Thanks I will search about this

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: There's `#pragma pack`, but that isn't portable and requires care. For something a little better, [try this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/054edbd79dc797a5).

Comment: You could reduce the size somewhat if you list your members in the order of descending size. Here, it will get the structure down to 16 bytes large.

Comment: To reduce the memory you could use 'char ch[11]' and pack/unpack the other elements into it. NASTY as all heck.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik great!

Comment: @robnick is there a way to do this without performance penalty when doing calculations?

Comment: @robnick - that might hurt on older ARM processors that don't tolerate misaligned data. Newer ARMs do tolerate it like x86, but it comes at a cost on both platforms (ARM and x86). If you are going to do that, you should use `-Wcast-align` and friends.

Comment: @noloader: Unaligned accesses on modern Intel architectures are near identical performance wise these days (I do say *near*, there can still be cache issues), but you're right, best to just reorder and let it be if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pragma pack` is usually what is used, but its not as portable as you'd like. Here's the docs on it:

- [Microsoft's pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx)
- [GCC's Structure-Packing Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html)

Both provide `#pragma pack(n)`, `push`, and `pop`.

In the absence of the packing, try reordering the `struct`:

```
struct st
{
    int *b;
    short a;
    char ch;
};
```

You have to be careful about accessing data if its packed. You will probably have to `memmov` (or `memcpy`) it out to ensure portability across all platforms. If you don't, then you could encounter a `EXCEPTION_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` on Windows or a `SIGBUS` error on Linux.

Microsoft has a good writeup on it at [Windows Data Alignment on IPF, x86, and x64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

`-Wstrict-aliasing` and `-Wcast-align` will help you find the sore spots.

Comment: using pragma pack: a) will result in any speed hit, b) will I get this in exactly 11 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late and I know you already accepted an answer but this can also work.. You'll get 12 bytes.. NOT 11. I'm not sure if it's portable but I think it is. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas

```
#include <iostream>

struct alignas(char) aligned_struct
{
    short a;
    int *b;
    char ch;
};


int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(aligned_struct);
}
```

**EDIT:**

VS2012 does NOT include alignas in their compiler according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx

It doesn't seem to need the above in VS2012 though. For some reason, with or without the above, it still prints 12:

```
struct aligned_struct
{
    short a;
    int* b;
    char ch;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(aligned_struct); //prints 12
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do I compile this in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Added an example for VS2012.