# Efficient way to store x64 pointer

Tags: c++

One x64 pointer needs 8 bytes memory. Is it possible to store this pointer in 2 4 bytes integers for memory alignment reasons?

The question is not "how to copy the bytes one by one" but rather "is there an automatic way to do this without sacrificing performance?"

Comment: If something needs to load the 64bits as a single value (like a pointer), then its probably going to need to be aligned.

Comment: Yes, but I will just store it as 2 4 byte ints and when I use it will unpack it.

Comment: "for memory alignment reasons" - what context is this in? I'd probably go with chars if I had to do something like this.

Comment: I want to do this without messing up with pragma: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010346

Comment: So you want to pack a struct, but you don't want to pay for the performance hit?

Comment: I guess this is like saying: I want both the food and my money, right?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you give some example code? You can certainly mask off the top and bottom 32-bits of the pointer and store them in integers, using (for example) `reinterpret_cast` or a C-style cast. This may not be strictly portable, but it's likely to work in practice. It's not clear why you'd want to do this, however.

Comment: please see here why I want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010346

Comment: Is the cost of unpacking this every time you use it less than the slight extra memory requirement of doing it the right way?

Comment: Great question but really this depends on how much CPU power the packing and unpacking uses. If you can recommend an unpacking method I can say. To be honest, in order to be beneficial, the packing unpacking must use almost no CPU power.

Comment: If I may ask, what purpose do you have for this structure?

Comment: Hmm. Very interesting. Unfortunately, I am new here (programming), and I don't see how packing methods of a pointer affect your original question. Also, judging from Mystical's past answers, he seems like the man for the job.